# Save a macro to run on different files

Tags: excel, vba

Let’s say I have an excel file called “file.xlsx” and a macro file called “macro.xlsm”.

The “macro.xlsm” is not a part of “file.xlsx” yet, but I want to be able to run the macro on the file given some arguments. How do I connect the macro to the file and run it?

Thanks for answering this noob question :)

Comment: Within macro.xlsm you can refer to the other workbook as ActiveWorkbook (if the other workbook is the active one) or Workbooks("file.xlsx").  If you have a specific macro you're working with it might be useful to post that so folks can make specific edits ...

Comment: Convert the code to an XLAM file that is always part of your Excel. Then you can run it no matter which workbook you have open.

Comment: Open both files. In `Excel` select `file.xlsx` and goto `Developer>Macros`. In the window titled `Macro`, nearer to the bottom under `Macro in:` choose `macro.xlsm` or `All Open Workbooks` and from the list above `double-click` the macro you want to use or `click` on the macro once and `click Run`. It would be best you posted the code of the macro, so it can be adjusted as Tim Williams mentioned earlier. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62122242/edit) button below your post.